# How do I disable the lock screen when resuming from suspend or hibernate without losing ability to lock screen manually?

Tags: 11.10, suspend, hibernate, lock-screen

I would like to bypass the password prompt after resuming from suspend or hibernate in Ubuntu 11.10. I tried:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'
```

But doing so I couldn't lock the screen manually any more by hitting Ctrl+Alt+L. It also removed the "Lock Screen" menu item on the power button menu that I get when I click on the top right of the screen. I would like to keep these two features while just removing the lock screen when the system resumes. Any ideas?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: It's a basic feature of gnome. It is not possible to change it now. Lock-screen disable only ensure that when your LED goes black (after some idle time) it will not lock the session.

Comment: Doing that command lets me avoid lock during hibernation and preserves my ability to lock the screen in MATE 17.04

Answer (score 2):

In 12.04 the option to turn off the screen lock does not remove the option to lock the screen from the power/cog button.

1. Click the power/cog button in upper right
2. Go to system settings
3. Click on Brightness and Lock
4. Slide the slider for Lock to off

All done!